# Make a grid map in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, masking

I want to draw a grid map based on the temperature values in Leaflet.

Similar to the illustration below.
[image: Example]

**Input data:** lat, lon, temperature values, cities' names

**Parameters:** the dimensions of the grid might be about 1-0.5 degree square.

At first, I thought plot markers(icon) 1 degree at a time is the best way, but I couldn't change the marker size from pixels.

What should I do? I wonder if I need GeoJSON for that?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to GIS.se Your question needs more details, before we can answer it. What kind of data do you have (For Temperature)? What would be the dimensions of the  grid? How are you planning on aggregating the temperature data on that grid? Do you have a renderer that you would apply to the grid to set the colours?

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your questions.

1.　lat/lon, temperature, name of cities

2. I think about 1-0.5 degree square.

3. At the worst, make like a dot painting by hand.....

4. I have QGIS, but I'm uncertain whether I will able to use it.

Comment: Here is a small grid http://jsfiddle.net/winsent/bh8mdefx/14/

Comment: Is there just one city (data point) per grid cell? Or, what should be the behaviour when there are more than one city (data point) per cell? Average the data, choose only one, something else?

Comment: >To Mapperz 
Thank you. But I am ignorant, I didn't get it.... 
>To IvanSanchez
Cities are multiple, and cell display maximum value.